# Проблемы с полями datetime при миграции legacy базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, django

Имеется старая база MySQL с PHP-сайта. Я её перенёс согласно [этой](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/) документации.

Получилось красиво:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    id_art = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_section = models.BigIntegerField()
    id_t = models.BigIntegerField()
    id_ct = models.BigIntegerField()
    fesid = models.IntegerField()
    postpone_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_art = models.DateTimeField()
    status_art = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    title_art = models.TextField()
    meta_art = models.TextField()
    short_art = models.TextField()
    full_art = models.TextField()
    foto_art = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    foto_art_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sort_art = models.IntegerField()
    map_art = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    coordinates_art = models.TextField()
    vk_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nl2br = models.IntegerField()
    id_man = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'articles'
```

Затем я её переделал под нужды нового проекта в несколько миграций. Получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    id_art = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_art = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=250)
    id_section = TreeForeignKey(SectionArt, db_column='id_section', verbose_name='Категория')
    fesid = models.ForeignKey(Fedsubj, db_column='fesid', verbose_name='Регион')
    id_ct = ChainedForeignKey(
        Cities,
        chained_field='fesid',
        chained_model_field='fesid',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        db_column='id_ct',
        verbose_name='Город'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Дата создания',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_column='date_art',
    )
    meta_art = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Мета')
    short_art = models.TextField(verbose_name='Короткое описание', max_length=300)
    full_art = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='Содержание')
    foto_art = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Изображение')
    foto_art_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Описание изображения')
    coordinates_art = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Координаты')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'articles'
        verbose_name = u'Новость'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Новости'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_art

    def category_name(self):
        return self.id_section.get_root().title_sec

    category_name.short_description = u'Раздел'
```

И теперь при миграции происходит что-то очень странное:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'postpone_until' at row 3595")
```

Несмотря на то, что я уже удалил `postpone_until' в своей миграции. Кстати, вот она:

```
operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='date_art',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='id_man',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='id_t',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='map_art',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='nl2br',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='postpone_until',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='sort_art',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='status_art',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='vk_id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column='date_art', null=True, verbose_name='\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u0441\u043e\u0437\u0434\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='coordinates_art',
            field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='\u041a\u043e\u043e\u0440\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0442\u044b'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='fesid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='fesid', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='articles.Fedsubj', verbose_name='\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='foto_art',
            field=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=b'', verbose_name='\u0418\u0437\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='foto_art_text',
            field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438\u0437\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='full_art',
            field=ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='\u0421\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='id_art',
            field=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='id_ct',
            field=smart_selects.db_fields.ChainedForeignKey(auto_choose=True, chained_field='fesid', chained_model_field='fesid', db_column='id_ct', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='articles.Cities', verbose_name='\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='id_section',
            field=mptt.fields.TreeForeignKey(db_column='id_section', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='articles.SectionArt', verbose_name='\u041a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='meta_art',
            field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='\u041c\u0435\u0442\u0430'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='short_art',
            field=models.TextField(max_length=300, verbose_name='\u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043a\u043e\u0435 \u043e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articles',
            name='title_art',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='\u0417\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e\u043a'),
        ),
    ]
```

Как с этим бороться?

---

### UPD

`sqldiff` только сильнее меня запутал

```
    ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `id_t`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `postpone_until`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `status_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `sort_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `map_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `vk_id`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `nl2br`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `id_man`;
CREATE INDEX `articles_id_section`
        ON `articles` (`id_section`);
CREATE INDEX `articles_fesid`
        ON `articles` (`fesid`);
CREATE INDEX `articles_id_ct`
        ON `articles` (`id_ct`);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `id_art` integer AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `title_art` varchar(250);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `id_section` integer;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `foto_art` varchar(100);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `date_art` DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `meta_art` DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `coordinates_art` DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Установите ```django-extensions``` и попробуйте посмотреть в чём разница через команду ```sqldiff``` - это покажет что могло неправильно мигрировать, например. Дальше посмотрим по обстоятельствам

Comment: Кстати, база то какая? Гуглится по подобной тематике mysql, но это только догадки

Comment: не совсем по теме, но: не заключайте кучу операций в миграцию, одна операция = одна миграция. это исключает возможность подвисшего состояния и всяких траблов с реордерингом операций (на что очень похож данный пример).

Comment: @Etki то, что вы видите -- 14-я миграция

Comment: @Etki мешать несколько операций в одну миграцию можно, это нормальная практика. Лучше не смешивать datamigration и schemamigration, это да

Comment: @FeroxTL сто раз нет. Никаких данных в миграциях вообще не должно быть (иначе их нельзя откатывать), никаких объединений - тоже (иначе есть вероятность падения миграции посередине, а это автоматически требует ручного вмешательства).

Comment: @Etki невозможность откатить данные в случае ошибки - это проблема баз, не поддерживающих DDL. Если вы выбрали MyISAM, то вы сами себя обрекли на страдания. В худшем случае просто придётся всё это учитывать. Данные в миграциях тоже допустимы, если вы отдаёте себе отчёт о том, когда они будут создаваться. В последних версиях django даже фикстуры через миграции загружаются.

Comment: @FeroxTL вы не можете откатить данные, потому что не знаете, пользователь их установил, или бездшная машина. А то что какие-то там разработчики запихнули seed не туда, где он должен быть - лишний повод не работать с этими разработчиками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл причину ошибки: в столбце `postpone_until` у одной из записей было проставлено `00.00.0000 00:00:00`. После ручного удаления миграция заработала. Только вот все даты из `date_art` удалились.

---

```
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `id_t`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `postpone_until`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `status_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `sort_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `map_art`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `vk_id`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `nl2br`;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        DROP COLUMN `id_man`;
CREATE INDEX `articles_id_section`
        ON `articles` (`id_section`);
CREATE INDEX `articles_fesid`
        ON `articles` (`fesid`);
CREATE INDEX `articles_id_ct`
        ON `articles` (`id_ct`);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `id_art` integer AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `title_art` varchar(250);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `id_section` integer;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `foto_art` varchar(100);
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `date_art` DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `meta_art` DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
        MODIFY `coordinates_art` DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Так у вас миграции не применены судя по sqldiff, как заработало то?

Comment: Так после устранения этой ошибки они применились

Comment: Стоило ещё тогда вывести список применённых миграций, я думал у вас внезапно всё сыпаться начало

Comment: @FeroxTL в том-то и дело, что сыпалось. Ведь удаление старой колонки и создание новой были всунуты в одну миграцию.
https://gist.github.com/dukeimg/9d8d1b0cfe5ecb986b0009266924b2ed Так что Etki в чём-то прав: упрощая миграции легче отслеживать ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Я предположу по sqldiff, что реально миграция у вас не выполнилась, которая должна была удалить столбцы, не выполнилась.

Я уже рассказывал про [внутреннее устройство системы миграции в django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541384/176345). В общем у меня подозрения, что внутренняя система миграций django считает, что у вас managed = False (несмотря на то, что по факту наоборот). Либо считала в какой-то период времени (в это время миграции у вас вероятнее всего работали фейково, хотя визуально применялись). Проверить это можно теми же `django-extensions` функцией `sqlmigrate`, указав ей одну из тех миграций, что должны были удалить столбцы, но не выполнили этого. Пример:

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate core 0018
```

Если sql отображается, значит мои предположения ложны и дальше можно не читать.

Что необходимо проверить далее

Во-первых найдите миграцию, которая непосредственно создавала эту таблицу. К сожалению покопавшись в своих проектах я не нашёл тот коммит, которым я исправлял у себя подобный баг. Выглядеть должно примерно так - лучше найдите и отобразите в вопросе

```
    migrations.CreateModel(name=u'Profile', fields=[(
        # ...
    ],
        options={},
        bases=(u'accounts.baseuser',),
        managers=[
             # ...
        ]),
```

Нас интересует словарь `options` - иногда туда попадает `swappable`, `managed = False`, `proxy = True` и другие конструкции. Необходимо проверить этот словарь на данные конструкции. Если имеются - удалить, миграции откатить до нужного места (чтоб не потерять данные, смотрите по ситуации) и провести заново